# jquery hide div function not working proper

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, triggers

I have this code:

```
jQuery('.hoverbgpfthnailiface').click(function(e){
    var target = e.target;

    while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;
    if(target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA'){
        jQuery('.header-search-form').css({ 'display' : 'none' });
    }
});
```

The strange this is that if I put it on Chrome Console it's working but when I add it on my files is not working and is not displaying any errors in Console. 
Any idea why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting the code in a ready function?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

    jQuery('.hoverbgpfthnailiface').click(function(e){
         var target = e.target;

         while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;
         if(target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA'){
              jQuery('.header-search-form').css({ 'display' : 'none' });
         } 
    });

});
```

Tell me if that worked for you :)

**EDIT**
Just one thing, in case you are interested, in a jQuery event when the binded function is called, `this` is the same as `e.target`

**EDIT2**
You're executing your code before the elements with the class of hoverbgpfthnailiface exists. 
You are creating them in line 2716, and because the $(document).ready is below the one you used in the code of the question it's executed later.

So I recommend you try moving the code from line 103 to 2717

Comment: Not really, because I already have this in ready function, what I've posted is just a part from the code

Comment: Ok, I'll need a little bit more info then. Have you tried using `console.log` to see the value of the variables?. The ready suggestion it's because it could have happened that the elements weren't in the page when you add the script to the files, but they were later.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use console.log for this specific issue, if you want to take a look at my website is [here](http://ibizapartypeople.com) and the code that contains this is starting at line 71 if you view source

Comment: Not really, I've put the code where you said but still the same. Maybe I have to add also a ready function? Now that part of code is on line 2720.

Comment: Yup, you'll have to put it bellow `g_fgenxtthumbalt();` but inside a ready (because if you don't you can't assure it'll be executed in that order. Tell me if you can fix it :D

Comment: One more question, is it possible also to trigger 2 divs like this jQuery('.hoverbgpfthnailiface, #header').click(function(e) ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, check this link if you're in doubt: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ . Please accept the answer if I helped :). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to use a jQuery function, you could use basic JS:

try:

```
document.getElementById('your element name').style.display = 'none';
```

Let me know if that was helpful.